Cannot access to my home server via WireGuard
I am trying set up vpn to get access to my home server.
I created a domain on Duck DNS, configure a cron, make a port forwarding on router(51820), install pivpn on server with created public DNS, create a user and still have no access to my home server from different ISP.
Also ping port via nmap, and it's open.
What am I doing wrong?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

add Wireguard network and your home LAN network in the AllowedIPs on the work computer. Don't use 0.0.0.0/0.
If your home network is 192.168.1.0/24
And your Wireguard tunnel is using 10.5.5.0/24
On your work computer Wireguard config:
AllowedIPs = 10.5.5.0/24,192.168.1.0/24
You can limit the allowed range more based on your needs, but that's a good starting place.

So, The problem was that my network was working in CGNAT
References:
Carrier-grade NAT
